# SQL merge with most frequent entries

Tags: sql

I would like to do a small report on the fill rates of some tables that I have. The central table is the people table. The feature table is connected via the ID to the people table. The number of features is different for each person, but specific to a country.

I would like to report on the fill rates of the tables (easy for the people table, but a little harder for the feature table). I'd like to display the fill rate for e.g. the two most frequent features of each country.

The people table:

| ID | CountryCode | Name | Address |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | US | Bob | 123 Fake Street |
| 2 | CA | Alice | Shelbyville |
| 3 | US | Charly |  |
| 4 | CA | Dora | Springfield |

The feature table:

| ID | feature_name | feature_value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | featureA | BlaA |
| 1 | featureB | BlaB |
| 1 | featureC | BlaC |
| 1 | featureD | BlaD |
| 2 | featureE | BlaE |
| 2 | featureF | BlaF |
| 3 | featureA | BlaA |
| 3 | featureC | BlaC |
| 4 | featureE | BlaE |

I would expect something like:

| CountryCode | Name | Address | feature_name1 | feature_1_fillrate | feature_name2 | feature_2_fillrate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| US | 1.0 | 0.5 | featureA | 1.0 | featureC | 1.0 |
| CA | 1.0 | 1.0 | featureE | 1.0 | featureF | 0.5 |

How would I get that fill rate report with a SQL statement?
I see two approaches:

- Calculate the fill_rates for each table by country (needs a join) and join the aggregated results on country
- Join the two most frequent features to the raw people table. This is more flexible w.r.t. group by on other fields, but I am struggeling to come up with a SQL statement for that.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to get the fill rate report using SQL:

```
WITH people AS (
  SELECT *, COUNTIF(ID IS NOT NULL) OVER() AS total_people
  FROM people_table
),
features AS (
  SELECT ID, feature_name, 
    COUNTIF(feature_value IS NOT NULL) OVER (PARTITION BY feature_name) AS feature_fill_rate,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC) AS feature_rank
  FROM feature_table
  GROUP BY 1, 2
),
top_features AS (
  SELECT ID, feature_name, feature_fill_rate
  FROM features
  WHERE feature_rank <= 2
),
country_stats AS (
  SELECT 
    CountryCode, 
    COUNT(DISTINCT ID) / MAX(total_people) OVER () AS people_fill_rate,
    MAX(IF(feature_rank = 1, feature_fill_rate, NULL)) AS top_feature_fill_rate, 
    MAX(IF(feature_rank = 2, feature_fill_rate, NULL)) AS second_feature_fill_rate
  FROM people
  LEFT JOIN top_features USING (ID)
  GROUP BY 1
)
SELECT * 
FROM country_stats
```